# Why is my coroutine ran repeatedly after function finishes?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm currently in a network service, where im adding an interceptor and listening for a 401. If a 401 happens, i then want to sign the user out and navigate back to my LoginActivity. This all works as expected, except the coroutine keeps being ran even after navigating to LoginActivity, causing new activities to be created constantly. Is there a way i can cancel this coroutine once the navigation has happened?

```
  val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder().apply {

            addInterceptor {

                val token = runBlocking {
                    tokenStore.getToken().first()?.token
                }

                val response = it.proceed(
                    it.request().newBuilder()
                        .addHeader(HEADER_AUTH, "Bearer $token")
                        .addHeader(HEADER_ACCEPT, "application/json").build()
                )

                if (response.code == 401) {
                    GlobalScope.launch {
                        signout(
                            tokenStore,
                            manager,
                            context
                        )
                    }
                    context.startActivity(
                        Intent(context, LoginActivity::class.java).setFlags(
                            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                        )
                    )
                }
                response
            }
            addInterceptor(HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {
                level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
            })
        }.build()
```

Comment: It is not recommended to use `GlobalScope`. It is not bound to any job. Global scope is used to launch top-level coroutines which are operating on the whole application lifetime and are not cancelled prematurely. Active coroutines launched in GlobalScope do not keep the process alive. They are like daemon threads. I think you need to rethink about your app architecture and launch coroutines only in `ViewModel` class using `viewModelScope` or in `Activity/Fragment` using `lifecycleScope`.

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues with this code:

1. You are launching multiple coroutines (`runBlocking` + `launch`)
2. In case of multiple concurrent calls that fail, each one will start `LoginActivity`

For 1) you need to wrap the whole interceptor call in `runBlocking`, so you can write suspend functions freely

For 2) you can use a [Mutex](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.sync/-mutex/) to make sure the interceptor runs once at a time